# pack() method of JFrame doesn't work (java,ubuntu)

Tags: java, swing, ubuntu

i'm new in java .
i just learn JPanel and JFrame.
i got this note from java software solutions:

> " The pack method of the frame sets its size appropriately based on
>   its contents—in this case the frame is sized to accommodate the size
>   of the panel it contains."

so i wrote this code :

```
public static void main (String [] args){
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("test");
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    JLabel label1= new JLabel("");
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.pack();
    //frame.setSize(1000, 500);
    frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
    Color darkBlue = new Color(8,40,94);
    panel.setSize(1000, 500);
    panel.setBackground(darkBlue);
}
```

but it the result is a really tiny window that i should maximize it with mouse to see the content
but when i set frame size every thing work great!
and i use Ubuntu.
so what's the reason of this problem?

Comment: You packed it while it was empty. Call `pack()` after all the other stuff. Also you might need to use `setPreferredSize` instead of `setSize` on the panel for `pack()` to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the order of your code:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("test");
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
JLabel label1= new JLabel("");
frame.setVisible(true);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.pack();
```

You did not add anything into the frame before you `pack()` it. `pack()` means let the frame decide its size based on the components being added to it.

Since you have no components added to it before you `pack()` it, you receive a small window with visually nothing inside (until you resize the window).

When the frame is being resized, paintManager will be consulted to paint the contentPane, hence if you add before pack(), not only the frame will be resized nicely for you, the components within it will be painted as well.

---

To see the components within the JFrame:

```
public static void main (String [] args){
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("test");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    JLabel label1= new JLabel("");
    panel.add(label1);    //Add label to panel
    frame.add(panel);     //Add panel (with label) to frame 
    frame.pack();         //Let the frame adjust its size based on the added components
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: tnx for your great answer ,so we should take  order of containers one by one right?

Comment: @AliZeynali Yes, order does matters, but ultimately still depending on what you want to do. Another thing is, you may consider having a customied JPanel so you won't have to code everything in the `main()` method.

Answer (score 4):

```
public static void main (String [] args){
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("test");
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    JLabel label1= new JLabel("");
    Color darkBlue = new Color(8,40,94);
    panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1000, 500));
    panel.setBackground(darkBlue);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    //frame.setSize(1000, 500);             
    frame.getContentPane().add(panel);      
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true); 
}
```

You should use pack() after setting the sizes.
Furthermore panel.setPreferredSize() works better than setSize() for you :)

Answer (score -1):

call jframe.pack() before jframe.setVisible() method !

public static void main (String [] args){

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("test");
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
JLabel label1= new JLabel("");
panel.setSize(1000, 500);    
frame.getContentPane().add(panel); 
Color darkBlue = new Color(8,40,94);
panel.setBackground(darkBlue);
frame.pack() ;
frame.setVisible(true); }
```

You will also need to check the default layout of JFrame , which is flow layout !